# Issue with Grid view in .NET 4.0 but it works fine in .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I migrated my application from 3.5 to 4.5. All the features works fine on .NET 4.5. But since my production server is Windows 2003 R2 Server I had to downgrade my .NET to 4.0.

I get the following error when I select a row in gridview.

Exception:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView 
        runat="server"
        ID="Gridview1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
        OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand"
        OnRowDataBound="Gridview1_RowBound"
        CellPadding="4"
        GridLines="None"
        AllowPaging="True"
        OnPageIndexChanging="Gridview1_PageIndexChanging"
        PageSize="10"
        EmptyDataText="Search returned (0) records.">

    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridRow" />
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="GridEditRow" />
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridSelectedRow" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRow" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkBox" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

HOT FIXES: KB2600088-x86.exe,KB2836939-v3-x86.exe. I tried both hot fixes none of them fixed my issue.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: One of issues that probably can't be fixed in any other way than installing 4.5, if none of hotfixes works. We had the same issue and were forced to migrate to 4.5. But this was quite some time ago.

Comment: Actually it is the script manager causing issue. I caught the above error OnAsyncPostBackError.